# Echo git message / output from a git pull and git fetch into txt file

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I have a repository in the cloud. For my personal needs I am trying to backup (yeah it's stupid I know) on my own server. I've already installed git there and using it through Windows command line.

I created a task which runs every day at 11 pm to fetch / pull the last changes from the cloud.

Now I want to output the result into a txt file after a fetch or pull. How do I do that?

My bat file looks like below. Somehow this doesn't work and only the text "Already up to date." comes up.

```
d:
cd D:\git\myRepo
echo: >> log.txt
echo %date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr >> log.txt
git fetch .>> log.txt
echo: >> log.txt
git pull .>> log.txt 
echo: >> log.txt
```

Comment: Just `fetch` fetches from a location you have set up in the past. Probably put in the explicit remote name and branch name, or fetch and pull all branches if you really want to have a complete clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting one to troubleshoot. The problem is with the `.` in `.>>`. I first assumed `.>>` was part of the the Windows cmd redirect syntax, but it's not. What you're running is in fact `git fetch .` and `git pull .` and appending the log of those commands to `log.txt`. Replace `.>>` by `>>` and you're set.

If you want stderr to be saved in `log.txt` along with stdout, which is what I assumed `.>>` was for when I first read the question, this worked for me:

```
d:
cd D:\git\myRepo
echo: >> log.txt
echo %date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr >> log.txt
git fetch >> log.txt 2>&1
echo: >> log.txt
git pull >> log.txt 2>&1
echo: >> log.txt
```

Back to `git fetch .` and `git pull .`, my experiments bring me to conclude that `.` is a reference to your current sandbox, which would explain why pulling/fetching from `.` always says `Already up to date.` I came to this conclusion by comparing `git remote show .` and `git remote show origin`, though I could not find any documentation for `.` used this way.